# MATLAB: Subscripted assignment between dissimilar structures

Tags: arrays, matlab, structure

I'm trying to perform a very basic assignment in matlab to create an array of structures.
Here's the main code for assigning it

```
for i=1:n
    P(i) = MakePoint(x(i), y(i), z(i));
end
```

Where the function `MakePoint` is

```
 function P = MakePoint(x,y,z)
    % P is a point with x-coordinate P.x and y-coordinate P.y.
        P = struct('x',x,'y',y,'z',z)
    end
```

In other words, I'm trying to make `P` and array of "points" creates with `MakePoint`. I get the error

> Subscripted assignment between dissimilar structures

How do I fix this?
Thank you!

Comment: You can't put a `struct` inside an array. You can make `P` a cell array though: `P{i}=MakePoint(x(i),y(i),z(i))`.

Comment: @David, this is not correct. you can have an array of structs. the only restriction is that all the struct array elements has the same field names at the same order.

Comment: What is the value of `P` before the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear why your code gives this error.

However, a nicer way of setting an array of structs is using cell-array arguments:

```
P = struct('x', mat2cell(x), 'y', mat2cell(y), 'z', mat2cell(z) );
```

and no loop is required.

You can try it out [here](http://ideone.com/gS1Dkw).